# Whole table not showing in JSON when doing Hibernate mapping

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, mapping

The table is created successfully and filled with information in H2 database as seen here:
[image]

When using Spring boot to display this table information with JSON format i only see this:
[image]

Here you can see the code snippet from the object

```
package com.share.sharelt.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "item_rental")
public class ItemRental {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "created")
    private Date created;

    @Column(name = "cost")
    BigDecimal cost;

    @Column(name = "rent_begin")
    private Date rentBegin;

    @Column(name = "rent_end")
    private Date rentEnd;

    @Column(name = "is_confirmed")
    private boolean isConfirmed;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "renter_id", nullable = true)
    private User user;

    public ItemRental(){};

}
```

The problem is that i want to see the whole table information, more specifically the "renter_id" column

Comment: As I can see `renter_id` is a field in `item_rental` table, why don't you add it to Entity class?

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to create a `DTO` class which is gonna be a `JSON` wrapper to your `ItemRental` entity

Something like `ItemRentalDTO` and  `UserDTO`  with all fields of `ItemRental` and `User` entity class

Link: https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application